# Multi module java app project structure

Tags: java, spring-boot, multi-module, project-structure

I am getting task(for learning new technologies) to create a facebook like project with

**1**. Auth (Spring Boot,Spring security, MySQL, ember.js)

**2**. Messaging (Spring Boot, Kafka,Cassandra, ember.js)

**3**. Member (Spring Boot, ember.js)

**4**. Reporting (Kafka, Spark, ember.js)

functional.

I need to get help for project structure. Should I have four separated  modules (like auth, message, member, report) + core module. And what I should put in core module(entity beans, helpers, utils...)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping code organized on huge projects is important, making each functionality into it's own module is desired. 
But only if you are experienced enough should you begin with that. It might be better to start off in one module and expand later into separate modules.

In the core you construct tests that determine if the application as a whole is functional, etc. Core could also include the REST for everything else than the modules you already said.

Or do you plan to make the front with react?

Comment: Oh no, core should be done with ember.js . Thanks